# My JavaScript code doesn't want to work

Tags: javascript

I'm a newbie okay? I just don't get what is wrong with my code, if someone could fix it please explain to me...

Code:

```
<script>
var userMoney:10;
var userChoice = prompt("Okay young lad, you've got 3 choices, either you choose box 1,      2 or 3");
if(userChoice==="1"){
confirm("Wow. You're just that lucky, you've got 10$ added to your account");
}
if(confirm("Wow. You're just that lucky, you've got 10$ added to your account"){
userMoney:10+10;
}
var yesno = prompt("Would you like to see how much money you've got lad?");
if(yesno==="yes"){
confirm(userMoney)
} else {
confirm("Well lad I Guess that's the end of the game.");
}
if(userChoice==="2"){
confirm("Oi, bad luck Brian better luck next time");
}
if(userChoice==="3"){
confirm("Oi, bad luck Brian better luck next time");
}
</script>
```

Comment: What's going wrong? Is the output incorrect? Is it throwing errors? (First error: it should be `var userMoney = 10;`)

Comment: That's not either valid JavaScript...

Comment: Fix your assignments : should be =  (var userMoney = 10;)

Comment: What is `userMoney:10+10;`?

Comment: We all start *somewhere* people.  (It's just that some people need to start with the documentation)

Comment: And you're missing at least one closing parenthesis.

Comment: When you run your program, the console will tell you what errors are occurring where.

Comment: here's a working example read about alert and confirm http://jsfiddle.net/ncubica/CyqfX/ best

Answer (score 3):

```
var userMoney:10;
```

should be `var userMoney = 10;`

```
userMoney:10+10;
```

could either be: `userMoney = userMoney + 10;` or `userMoney += 10;`

Answer (score 2):

Your first line should read:

```
var userMoney=10;
```

You used a : instead of an = in several places.

Also, in the future, use a tool like http://jsfiddle.net/ to review your scripts

Answer (score 0):

change userMoney=10+10;
and also change
userMoney=10